# Crash Google Cast - Security SSLRecordServiceWriteQueueInternal

Tags: ios, swift, crash, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have crash in Google Cast SDK.

Crashlytics logs:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x189bd7014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x189c9f450 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x189b4b400 abort + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x189c0d944 szone_size + 658
4  Security                       0x18b019cdc SSLRecordServiceWriteQueueInternal + 132
5  Security                       0x18b01cbf8 SSLServiceWriteQueue + 20
6  Security                       0x18b01cd80 SSLWrite + 212
7  GoogleCast                     0x1007c269c __46-[GCKNSSLSocket sslPrivateInitWithBufferSize:]_block_invoke.24 + 88
8  GoogleCast                     0x1007ccf70 -[GCKBCircularByteBuffer drainWithBlock:] + 96
9  GoogleCast                     0x1007c2f44 -[GCKNSSLSocket performCrypto] + 436
10 GoogleCast                     0x1007c2944 -[GCKNSSLSocket sendBytes:length:partialOK:] + 64
11 GoogleCast                     0x10070711c -[GCKCastSocket sendMessage:] + 200
12 GoogleCast                     0x1006edd84 -[GCKCastDeviceConnector sendMessageWithNamespace:toDestinationID:stringPayload:binaryPayload:] + 516
13 GoogleCast                     0x1006eee04 -[GCKCastDeviceConnector sendBinaryMessage:withNamespace:toDestinationID:] + 84
14 GoogleCast                     0x1006e7cec -[GCKCastChannel sendBinaryMessage:toDestinationID:error:] + 144
15 GoogleCast                     0x100711280 -[GCKDeviceAuthChannel sendChallengeWithPeerSecTrust:error:] + 376
16 GoogleCast                     0x1006ef1d4 -[GCKCastDeviceConnector castSocket:didConnectWithPeerSecTrust:] + 532
17 GoogleCast                     0x100707dc4 __50-[GCKCastSocket notifyDidConnectWithPeerSecTrust:]_block_invoke + 84
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x189a921fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x189a921bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x189a96d68 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
21 CoreFoundation                 0x18abb6810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
22 CoreFoundation                 0x18abb43fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18aae22b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
24 GraphicsServices               0x18c596198 GSEventRunModal + 180
25 UIKit                          0x190b297fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
26 UIKit                          0x190b24534 UIApplicationMain + 208
27 Kanopy PROD                    0x100079860 main (AppDelegate.swift:19)
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x189ac55b8 (Missing)
```

Why does this crash occur? Is this crash in the SDK or is it possibly due to incorrect integration of the Chrome Cast SDK?

Security
SSLRecordServiceWriteQueueInternal

Crashlytics logs (image):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYSWR.png)

Code in another thread:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCCzf.png)

Comment: The Crashlytics will tell you the exact line of the crash. Can you show us that?

Comment: @Glenn, I have added info.

Comment: Create a bug report here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%2B